# Worksheet becomes workbook element

Tags: excel, vba, corrupt

I have an xlsm file where I am working (Office 365). My macro does a lot of things, reach some internet pages, communicates with Access database. I am working with References

```
VBA
Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
OLE Automation
Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft XML, v6.0
Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 2.8 Library
Also I am savinig my file on Onedrive folder.
```

The problem is that when I close the file and I re open it, A message pop up saying "We found a problem with some content in 'xxxxxxxx.xlsm'.

> Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the
>   source of this workbook, click Yes."

I click yes and control developer objects are gone from worksheet (buttons) and the real problem is that when I open VBA, One of the Sheets becomes a workbook object, and creates a new sheet with no code inside.

Worksheets have became Workbooks

[image]

I do not know if maybe is a conflict with the references or something with the onedrive server. Anyone have had a similar issue?

EDIT: I tried to copi all code to a new workbook with no differece. When re open the file seems to be corrupted, the worksheet trandformed into a workbook and a new worksheet was created.

Comment: I have seen this very occasionally: once it happens there's no recovering the workbook (in my experience at least) - it has become corrupted somehow.  Best you can do is copy all the code and your worksheets over to a new file.

Comment: I tried but did not work

Comment: If this is in onedrive I think you can go back to a version before it got corrupted? If you can recover it then I'd use the .xlsb format going forward: that seems to be slightly more reliable.   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/restore-a-previous-version-of-a-file-stored-in-onedrive-159cad6d-d76e-4981-88ef-de6e96c93893?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: I did but each time I executed It got currpted. As I shared in the post I could find the point where the code got the file corrupted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well after a lot of debugging I think I find the error. The real problem is when I tried to add a Validation in a Range.

```
With Sheets(H_CARGA).Range(rngInt & "," & strRango).Validation
        .Delete
        If strLst = "" Then
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:="A111,A112,B1,A0113,A0114,A0115,A0119,A0121,A0122,A0123,A0124,A0125,A0126,A0127,A0128,A0129,A0130,A0141,A0142,A0143,A0144,A0145,A0149,A150,A0161,A0162,A0163,A0164,A0170,A0210,A0220,A0230,A0240,A0311,A0312,A0321,A0322"
        Else
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:=strLst
        End If
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = title
        .ErrorTitle = title
        .InputMessage = msgV
        .ErrorMessage = msgEr
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

So two things APARENTLY are happening. 
First, the range. As you can see is a composed range. I merge the ranges with a comma ",". When I execute it from Excel, It finished well. When I execute it from VBA an error showed up about the character used to merge them. Apparently semicolon is the right one.
Second the list I am using as a Validation rule is like "A115,A456,A54,B556" that are strings really similar to cells references. So I guess at some point when the range is composed and separated by comma and the validation list is similar to a list of cells references, at some point when the file saves, it confuses the ranges, the  interpreter of the file at some point get crazy and following sintax rules ended to create new workbooks elements and worksheets.
I am 100% sure is a that point the file got corrupted. I do not know if this is worth to be reported or something to be checked.
My solution was to assure the merge character in Range is semicolon and not comma.

Thanks anyway

EDIT>

I tried to reproduce te error outside my project and I could. I started a new workbook with a very simple code. In Sheet1.cells(1,1) I stored the validation list

0;A;A01;A011;A0111;A0112;A0113;A0114;A0115;A0119;A012;A0121;A0122;A0123;A0124;A0125;A0126;A0127;A0128;A0129;A013;A0130;A014;A0141;A0142;A0143;A0144;A0145;A0149;A015;A0150;A016;A0161;A0162;A0163;A0164;A017;A0170;A02;A0210;A0220;A0230;A0240;A03;A031;A0311;A0312;A032;A0321;A0322;B;B05;B0510;B0520;B06;B0610;B0620;B07;B071;B0710;B072;B0721;B0722;B0723;B0729;B08;B081;B0811;B0812;B082;B0820;B089;B0891;B0892;B0899;B09;B091;B0910;B099;B0990

Then I run a veri simple routine

```
Sub testBug()
   With Sheet1.Range("N1:N100").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                xlBetween, Formula1:=Sheet1.Cells(1,1).Value
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = "title"
        .ErrorTitle = "title"
        .InputMessage = "msgV"
        .ErrorMessage = "msgEr"
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

When you run this, the validation rule is applied to the cells. You close the document and re open it, and it is corrupted. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, problem occurs when I open my xlsm workbook while  another macro workbook remains open. Then the worksheet that contains grouping ActiveX controls becomes workbook element.

I close the workbook without saving.
Ungroup ActiveX controls on that sheet solved my problem.
[image]